# How do you sort an array of objects properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I seem to be having a little issue getting an array of objects to sort properly.

For example, let's say I have the following:

```
var items = [
    {id: '1', itn: '1'},
    {id: '2', itn: '10P'},
    {id: '3', itn: '2'},
    {id: '4', itn: '3'}
];
```

I need to sort this array based on the value in "itn." However, when I run the function below I get it listed as 1, 10P, 2, 3 instead of 1, 2, 3, 10P.

```
userData.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.itn > a.itn) ? -1 : (b.itn < a.itn) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

I'm a bit stuck in how to go forward with this and am also unsure what kind of keywords to search for to get the correct guidance. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If both arguments to `<` are strings, it compares lexicographically; `"10P"` is before `"2"` just like `"aardvark"` is before `"b"`. `parseInt` if you want numeric comparison.

Comment: Note that this is an _array of objects_, not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to sort the array based on the integer part present in `itn`. To achieve that you can use `parseInt()` to convert the item (`itn`) to integer then compare those integer values:

```js
var userData = [
    {id: '1', itn: '1'},
    {id: '1', itn: '10P'},
    {id: '1', itn: '2'},
    {id: '1', itn: '3'}
];

var res = userData.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a.itn);
    b = parseInt(b.itn);
    return (b > a) ? -1 : (b < a) ? 1 : 0;
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Minor: Using the unary operator `+`, i.e `+'123'` will also parse a `String` to a whole `Number`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `numeric` property as `true`.

```js
var items = [{id: '1', itn: '1'},{id: '1', itn: '10P'},{id: '1', itn: '2'},{id: '1', itn: '3'}];
items.sort((a,b) => a.itn.localeCompare(b.itn, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(items);
```